# decrypting a particular message encrypted with RSA

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have a message encrypted by the RSA algorithm and I want to decrypt it. All I have is the public key (e,n) and the message. The original message is composed only of numbers from 0 to 25 (for example "1,20,15,9,..." with the comma serving just to separate the different numbers in the message), and each number in the original message is encrypted separately with RSA (so the resulting ciphertext would be like this "263674,276582,0,272765,...."). The problem is that e and n are very big so using the formula originalNumber^e mod n = encryptedNumber is not that easy.
 Does anyone know how to simply do that ?

Comment: Is that RSA modular exponentation (aka raw RSA) or is PKCS#1 v1.5 or OAEP padding used? In other words, how is the ciphertext generated? How large is the result?

Comment: @owlstead I updated my question. For the RSA used, it is the standard one with the use of m^e mod n for encryption and c^d mod n for decryption

Comment: You can simply brute force the messages. Just test all the possible input values and encrypt, see if it matches. For a computer, `e` does not seem very big. Note that you are using textbook (or RAW) RSA here, that's not how it is used in practice. See the PKCS#1 specifications to see how it can be secured.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Yes, I've taught about brute force but since e is very big (3 digits) you can't even calculate it. So, I don't know how to do that, because the number of attempts 26 is just feasible but however I think to calculate number^e is not possible

Comment: Well, if you can post here, you should have access to a device called a computer that thinks that 3 digits is just nothing at all. How big is N? No, don't tell me, 6 digits? Note that for RSA to be safe *when padding is used* it requires about 300 digits or more (a 1024 bit key). And your computer will break into some sweat from 100 digits onwards.

Comment: no I am talking about e equals to 543 and n having six numbers "652413"for example. That's why I said it was difficult for a computer since you should have the exact number for the modulo afterwards

Comment: How is that different from what I'm saying? Just encrypt each possibility yourself using the public key, see if it matches.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying, but for m from 0 to 25 when you try for example m^543 then the computer can't compute it

Comment: 12062149556671058207435761544634310848756342837263788193984025451676...834228515625 (left some digits out). But seriously, you only have to calculate it modulus n. Oh, and it takes 0 ms computing power on my 6 year old laptop.

Comment: for example in my computer when I try to compute 2^543 then it gives me just 2.879305e+163 so you just can't do the modulo after that

Comment: Well, maybe you should try a programming language that supplies modular exponentiation (e.g. Java with `BigInteger`). This *is* stackoverflow. For the initial calculation I used Wolfram-Alpha, but for the timing I used the venerable `bc` on the unix command line.

Comment: To clarify here - to calculate `M^e mod n`, for anything but the most trivial values of `e`, you *don't* just calculate `M^e` and then take the modulo, you perform [**modular exponentiation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).